# How to modify the default permissions for files saved by DolphinDB "saveText"?

Tags: dolphindb, umask

For the files saved by `saveText`, only the specific user has the write access, other members of the group are not allowed to write to the file. How to modify the configuration to give the write permissions to the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the write permissions match the permissions of the user who initiates the DolphinDB process. The other members of the same group are not allowed to write to the saved file due to the permission mask. To grant group permissions by default, you need to modify the permission mask by setting `umask 0002`.

If starting DolphinDB with systemd, you can add a configuration option to the relevant system configuration file:

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```